# Backbone.js model.get not retrieving value

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This is a really strange problem I'm having with an app in Backbone.js. I have different search results which are displayed in an accordion, only one result can be selected at a time.

The model for each result has an attribute, "selected" which represents whether the result is selected or not.

For some reason I'm not able to deselect the match. This is the code that's run on clicks on the result.

I've been looking through it, selected always returns false, and somehow, never gets set to true in this function.

```
click_header: function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var s = this.model.get("selected");
    if (s == true) {
        this.model.set({ selected: false, expanded:false});
    } else {
        this.model.set("selected", true, { silent: true });
        this.model.set("expanded", true, { silent: true });
    }

}
```

EDIT:
I fixed the problem. A function elsewhere in the program triggered by changes to select was setting select to false on all models.

Comment: what do you mean, it is not getting set? is it because you are silently updating when true?

Comment: It was actually falling through the if statement. Clicking the element multiple times and tracing through it with Chrome Dev tools, it's always going to the else. I have a feeling an event might be negating the effect of this somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem. A function elsewhere in the program triggered by changes to select was setting select to false on all models.

Answer (score -1):

**Updated** Here is a more streamlined approach:

```
click_header: function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var s = this.model.get("selected");
    this.model.set({ selected: !s, expanded: !s}, { silent: !s });
}
```

Comment: Care to explain anything? I hardly see how switching from one syntax to another can fix his problem.